# A Lagrangian function for tensors

Tags: tensors, lagrange-multiplier

I'm working on solving this kind of weird Lagrangian function like below:

$$ L_{X,U} = \| X \|_{1}^{TNN} + \lambda \| \hat{M}  U \| - \lambda_2 \| U -D X_{rs} \| + \beta_2 \| U - DX_{rs} \|_{F}^2 $$

where $X_{rs}$ is the reshaped version of $X$. Say, $X$ has shape $50 \times 3$ and $X_{rs}$ has shape of $25 \times 2 \times 3$. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.